# Drywall cracking and popping near window

Tags: drywall, windows, crack

Not sure if this paint is bubbling or something else. The drywall seems to be popping up near our window.

What could be the cause and the best way to repair this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just the tape coming off. If you had metal corners that would not happen.

Comment: Happens with metal corner bead as well. Either way, pull the old stuff off; put new on; retexture, paint.

Comment: Is it metal or paper tape?

Comment: There are comments assuming you may not wish to take off the plaster and paint covering the joint seam. If you do not wish to do that, you could try to simply etch that seam with a cutter knife and replaster with some acrylate paste in such a way that you try to match the old plaster texture (or is that wallpaper?). This may look bad, but you won't see the issue for a while. 
This is not the proper solution, but the quick, cheap and dirty one.

Comment: The large gob of caulking on the window sill makes me wonder what other repairs have already been attempted on this corner bead.

Answer (score 3):

That's almost certainly metal (or plastic) [corner bead](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/758aad06-f664-40d1-8cb9-4264a67b8663/svn/gibraltar-building-products-drywall-corner-bead-10524-64_1000.jpg), and the edge has lifted due to either careless installation or structural movement. Here's what I have done a few times as an initial surgical repair, with hope that it's a final fix.

1. Acquire some small-headed nails that are about 1-1/2" in length. They need to be rather thin and sharply pointed. Small heads are better, but they must be flat and thin. Finish nails tend to punch through or leave dimples.
   [image]
2. Drive a nail through a loose section of the corner bead, about 1/2" in from the edge, and to just above flush. To avoid deforming the bead and popping texture loose, drill through the metal first with a bit just larger than the nail shank.
3. Using a nail set, very carefully drive each nail just enough to snug the bead up against the drywall surface.
4. Add more nails until the entire bead edge is down and secure.
5. Rub a small amount of white painter's caulk into the cracked bead seam to fill it. Also dab the nail heads. Wipe any excess caulk off the wall with a lightly damp cloth.

At this point you may be done, depending on how well the white caulk blends. Otherwise, paint the repair, blending outward into the wall.

The damage could be the result of bead compression due to settling in the framing. If that's the case, and this fix doesn't last, you may need to pull the bead, install a new one with a small end gap, and refinish the drywall. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Total nonsense, the metal corner cover is stiff enough not to partially lift off

Comment: This is good advice, and I shamefacedly agree that my mind often wanders to a complete rebuild where a quicker fix might work perfectly well.

Comment: The rules here require to disclose the source of you picture ! you have been here for 7 Years, you should know that.

Comment: As a semi-pro photographer I usually do. Here, the image was unattributed to begin with and I modified it heavily for use here. Thanks, though. :D